# Why does my model suggest Gall is not significant, when the plot suggests it is?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, interpretation

I have trouble with interpreting the output of a general linear model, which I have fitted to some data. Here are my data:

```
     Gall  Site healthy unhealthy
1  absent Site1    1750        35
2  absent Site2    1642       146
3 present Site1    1146        23
4 present Site2     333        30
```

I have made a barplot to visualize this better:

[image: My barplot]

I want to test whether healthy or unhealthy (saplings) was induced by the galls being present or absent. The saplings were randomly collected in each site. Therefore, I fit a generalized linear model to these data:

```
abc <- glm(cbind(healthy,unhealthy)~Site*Gall, family="binomial", data=f1)
```

I summarize my model

```
summary(abc)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(healthy, unhealthy) ~ Site * Gall, family = "binomial", 
    data = f1)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            3.912023   0.170713  22.916  < 2e-16 ***
SiteSite2             -1.491959   0.191314  -7.798 6.27e-15 ***
Gallpresent           -0.003484   0.271097  -0.013    0.990    
SiteSite2:Gallpresent -0.009634   0.342474  -0.028    0.978    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.1069e+02  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.5963e-14  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 30.235

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

Now I try to simplify the model:

```
drop1(abc, test="Chi")

Single term deletions

Model:
cbind(healthy, unhealthy) ~ Site * Gall
          Df   Deviance    AIC        LRT Pr(>Chi)
<none>       0.00000000 30.235                    
Site:Gall  1 0.00079137 28.236 0.00079137   0.9776
```

I  omit the two-way interaction between `Site` and `Gall`:

```
> f1.rid1 <- update(abc, .~. - Site:Gall)
```

I test each 1-way term, each at a time:

```
> drop1(f1.rid1, test="Chi")
Single term deletions

Model:
cbind(healthy, unhealthy) ~ Site + Gall
       Df Deviance     AIC     LRT Pr(>Chi)    
<none>       0.001  28.236                     
Site    1  104.027 130.262 104.027   <2e-16 ***
Gall    1    0.004  26.239   0.003   0.9542    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

The model tells me to omit `Gall`, so my final model is

```
> f1.rid2 <- update(f1.rid1, .~., - Gall)
> summary(f1.rid2)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(healthy, unhealthy) ~ Site + Gall, family = "binomial", 
    data = f1)

Deviance Residuals: 
        1          2          3          4  
-0.014033   0.007093   0.017279  -0.015671  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.914420   0.148106  26.430   <2e-16 ***
SiteSite2   -1.494968   0.158755  -9.417   <2e-16 ***
Gallpresent -0.009518   0.165722  -0.057    0.954    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1.1069e+02  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7.9137e-04  on 1  degrees of freedom
AIC: 28.236

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

**My question is:**

Why am I dropping Gall in my model? I know the output tells me to do so, but by looking at the initial barplot, I figured the presence or absence of Gall must have a significant effect on healthy or unhealthy.

Comment: why are you running generalised linear model for categorical predictors?

Comment: Why not ? I am trying to figure out wether I can drop site or gall for my final model which would explain the counts

Comment: You don't need to use `drop1()`; note that the p-values are the same as in the `summary()` output. Also, there is an error in your `update(f1.rid1, .~., - Gall)`, the 2nd comma shouldn't be there. That's why `Gallpresent` is still in the last model. However, you don't need to drop it just because it isn't significant.

Answer (score 4):

Calculating the proportion unhealthy in each group and visualizing that might help you understand the model better.  There is no effect of Gall and a relatively strong effect of Site with no interaction present:

```
data1 <- data.frame(matrix(c( 0,0,1750,35, 
                              0,1,1642, 146,
                              1,0,1146,23,
                              1,1,333,30  ), 4, 4,byrow=TRUE))

names(data1) <- c("Gall", "Site","healthy","unhealthy")

data1$prop <- data1 $unhealthy/ ( data1 $healthy + data1 $unhealthy )

data1

>      Gall Site healthy unhealthy       prop
>    1    0    0    1750        35 0.01960784
>    2    0    1    1642       146 0.08165548
>    3    1    0    1146        23 0.01967494
>    4    1    1     333        30 0.08264463

library(ggplot2)

ggplot (data1, aes(Gall, Site, y=prop, fill=Gall)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
        facet_grid (~Site)
```

[image: GGplot Image]

Indeed, you can get these proportions directly from your fitted model as well.

```
glmfit1 <- glm( cbind(healthy,unhealthy) ~ Site * Gall, 
                      family = "binomial", data = data1  )

1- predict(glmfit1, type = "response")

>          1          2          3          4 
> 0.01960784 0.08165548 0.01967494 0.08264463
```

So, your variable selection procedure rightly drops Gall and the Site:Gall interaction term as they contribute nothing to the model.  Though, I would question the need to do any variable selection at all here as the model interpretation was sufficiently clear in the initial (full) model.

Answer (score 3):

@Brett has done a good job addressing the issue of why the model suggests Gall should be dropped.  I gather your question is motivated by an apparent inconsistency between your original plot and the modeling results.  Let me address that.

You state in the [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279359/interpreting-general-linear-model#comment535639_279359) that, "I am trying to figure out wether I can drop site or gall for my final model which would explain the counts".  Your data are counts in some sense, but not in the sense we normally mean by [counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_data) (e.g., [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) data).  Instead, you have counts out of a known total.  That means your data are [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  You do correctly specify the binomial distribution in the code for the model fits, but your barplot does not account for the known totals in displaying the counts.  *That* is why it gives the impression that there is an interaction and an effect of `Gall`.  @Brett's plot does display the counts as proportions of a known total, and so does not create that misleading perception.